# Is it possible to add a field to the Windows login screen?

Tags: windows, active-directory

Is it possible to add a custom field to the Windows login screen? So besides username and password I'd have to enter a value (which will be checked) for the third field? I assume some changes to Active Directory will be needed, unless this is not possible at all.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Active Directory.
You would need plugin-software that integrates with the login-screen to provide additonal features.
In your screenshot you already see 3 of those present (the icons at the bottom): Windows Hello, the Google login and another one (in the middle) which I don recognize that quickly.
And there exist more of these. Biometrics readers and 2FA tools often also use this mechanism to expand the standard logon.

So it can be done, but it isn't a matter of just doing some configuration in Active Directory. You will need software for it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no simple way to add another field to the login screen.  However, Microsoft and 3rd parties do offer solutions.  Search for [2 factor authentication for Windows login](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk00L5J5NhpoleftKNFQVD0a-_IBPUA%3A1587376159040&ei=H3CdXoL9AeyJytMPhYigCA&q=2%20factor%20authentication%20windows%20login&oq=2%20factor%20authentication%20windows%20login&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECCMQJzICCAAyBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yCAgAEBYQChAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIFCAAQzQIyBQgAEM0COgQIABBHOggIIRAWEB0QHlDmwgFYuu0BYNTvAWgCcAJ4AIABVYgB6QOSAQE2mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjCiNaA3fboAhXshHIEHQUECAEQ4dUDCAw&uact=5) and you will find some possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

MMMHMHMH

That IS a good idea, but windows 8 - 10 security is now one of the most secure services and you can't modify it. So no, it is no possible.

Comment: It is because many crap comment is coming from new users not knowing the system. The logic of the system is that first write some useful answers, then you can chit-chat. If you collect 200 rep on any sites (including SO), you get +100 rep gift everywhere. Thus, you will be able to comment everywhere without restriction. Your activity clearly shows that can collect 50 rep without any problem (for example, write 1-2 answers here, or about 3-4 on the Spanish SO - with the second, you will get the +100 gift).

Comment: Stack overflow doesn't share the rep points. I'm going to delete the answer and I'll wait

Comment: Yes, but if you get to 200 anywhere, you get +100 bonus everywhere. With this +100, you can comment everywhere. You have already about 130 on the Spanish SO.